# Modify value at given address with linker script

Tags: linker, ld, linker-scripts

I have a symbol that points to some value:

```
$ nm t3 | grep AAA
000000000040a140 D AAA
```

I want to modify the value at address `[AAA]` (the value at address `0x40a140`) using linker script. But I do no not see how to evaluate expressions with memory dereference. Are there any ways to do this with linker script?